# Removed Rows from Pandas Dataframe - Now Indexes Are Messed Up?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe in pandas that includes the genders of some patients. I wanted to sort by gender so I used:

```
df = df[df.Gender == 0]
```

but now when I print the dataframe I get something like:

```
    Gender
0     0
2     0
5     0
```

where the row indexes on the left stay what they were before the row removal and don't "resequence" back to 0, 1, 2 etc. making it difficult or impossible to iterate through right now. How could I resequence the row indexes?

Comment: Have you tried `df.reset_index()`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the results?  You should think of the index as a set of *labels*, with one label associated with each row.  The index for a given row is part of that row's data just like the columns are.  They're not meant to be purely sequential numbers, although you can set them to be that.

Comment: this should work `df[df.Gender==0].reset_index()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df[df.Gender == 0]
```

is taking a slice of `df` where `df.Gender` was equal to `0`.  This is as you expected.  It is also bringing along with it, the row indices for each of the rows that `df.Gender` was equal to `0`.  This is correct and has many wonderful benefits.

If you don't want to see that, and instead want it to be order from `0` to whatever, then do as the others have suggested you do in the comments.

```
df = df[df.Gender == 0].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, the reset_index method works! For this project I just need a quick way to remove those rows and pretend like they were never there in terms of indexes; I have a ID attribute that keeps track of the original information I would be losing anyway. I can appreciate the functionality but for now this should work. Thanks again!